# errors replacing development.sqlite3 with another development.sqlite3 on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am trying out an example from a book head first rails, i get to chapter 2 and i have issues following the instructions maybe because they used an older version of rails.

I am told to replace the development.sqlite3 file with the one provided on the site, and when i do so and try to run the run app again i get errors about **pending migrations**.

Note: 
1. I already ran my migration using `rake db:migrate` 
2. I downloaded the sqlite3 file and replaced the original file.
3. i started the server with `rails s` command.
4. I reload the page and then i get the error.

`ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

I have a feeling it has something to do with the schema.rb file? i dunno.
I'll really appreciate if someone can help me out here.
I have done my research, i've tried `rake db:reset` but to no avail. :(

see here: 
  [1]: http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfrails you can scroll down to the code download section under chapter 2.

Comment: I bet your migration timestamp is off. Do you have a sqlite GUI client?

Comment: @NickM yes i do, what do you suggest i do with the client? and well the migration timestamp may be off. but that aside any ideas?

Comment: Delete the migration timestamps and rerun the migrations